# Not redirecting after logging in

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and I am facing this problem i tried to solve this but was unable please need your help.
I want to make users first login and then access other pages they should not directly access the other pages.
 when i add the code it is not making users to access other pages without logging in it redirect user to login but it is not working in traditional way like when i put login info it brings back login page..
sorry for bothering 
here is the code

```
 <?php
// Start of Login Alert Code
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
  }

  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    header("location: login.php");
  }
  ?>
```

and here is code of login.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
    $user = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$user' && password='$pwd'";
    $data= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($data);
if($total==1)
{

 $_SESSION ['user_id']= $user;
    header('location:home.php');


   }

else {
    header('location:error.php');

}

}
?>
```

Comment: Where is `session_start()`

Comment: Make sure you have started a session with session_start() or setting session.auto_start in the php.ini .  https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839

Comment: There cannot be __any__ characters before the opening `<?php` tag when calling `header()`. Otherwise that will get outputted to the browser, and the browser will no longer be able to redirect. I noticed that there is a space before your <?php in your example code here - is that there in your source file? Additionally, you're referring to `$_SESSION` without calling `session_start()` - does that get called earlier in the script? Make sure there is nothing that could output characters (blank characters, errors, etc) before calling header().

Comment: i added session_start() still  issue remains same

Comment: @RToyo i did'nt get this point of no space before <?php where is space in the example? please can you help

Comment: You should use die or exit after doing a header redirect. Otherwise, the script will continue running.

Comment: @MaryBeauty2020 Sure, the space is only in your frist code example. I'll use an underscore to show where the space is: you have `_<?php` instead of just `<?php`. With that said, your second code sample doesn't have that, so it might not be the case. Make sure there are no new line characters before the opening of `<?php`. Additionally, the missing `session_start()` isn't the sole reason that your redirect is not working; that's a separate issue.

Comment: @RToyo thanks! i removed the space can you please help in sorting out this issue.. what is the solution.

Comment: @MaryBeauty2020 If that didn't do it, I can't see anything else in your code that looks bad. At this point we're starting to get into the realm of troubleshooting your code, which is outside the scope of StackOverflow (see #1: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I would suggest making sure that all errors are being displayed to you (take a look at this answer for how to get errors to display in your script, using `error_reporting` and `ini_set`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/4458445). Hopefully you'll see an error message that will give you some clues.

Comment: I did what was told now it is redirecting but access is open now.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Please try to define both the problem and the desired outcome in clear English. Also try to clearly state the context of both code snippets, and how they are related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different session variables

```
 isset($_SESSION['user'])
```

vs

```
 $_SESSION ['user_id']= $user;
```

A couple more things to be aware of: your SQL string there is perfect for SQL injection and you should hash the password stored in the database (check the php function [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)).

Comment: Also, the comment from @Harish.

Comment: i added still no change

Comment: @MaryBeauty2020: While it's unlikely that the session is what is causing the redirect problem, David brings up a good point about your SQL string. In addition to hashing passwords, you should never pass user input directly into a query (eg don't pass `$_POST['user']`). Instead, you should learn the concept of prepared statements (they're easier than they may first appear). If you google the term you'll find all sorts of helpful articles, but here's one of the first results I've grabbed off Google: https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: thanks @RToyo but first I want to solve redirecting issue than I will do a brief research on prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: login.php');
}

if (isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    session_destroy();
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

For login.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{
    $user = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$user' && password='$pwd'";
    $data= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($data);

    if($total==1)
    {

        $_SESSION ['user_id']= $user;
        header('location:home.php');
    }
}
else 
{
    header('location:error.php');
}
```

Comment: i added still no change

Comment: Its `session_start()` not `start_session()` sorry for the typo error.

Comment: still the issue is present

Comment: You need to close the if loop with `}` before else in `login.php` file

Comment: the first if statement also ?

Comment: I just updated my answer, please check and try it for once.